# Connection between Android phone and python server suggestion

Tags: android, python, sockets

how can i connect a server code python on PC with android mobile so that i be able to then and receive data between the server and the android mobile ??    but  put in consider that  the socket can not be open on the mobile android despite its open on the emulator and connect

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Android application to receive updates when things happen on the server, have you had a look at [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html)? One of the great things about this is that all Android applications share the same C2DM connection, so it is very light on battery usage.

Comment: i want my Android mobile to send to the server my current location the lat and long method appear to me (GPS) my current location i want this string method to be send to the server

Comment: Oh, you are going the other direction. In that case, check out the Apache HttpClient to save you writing a lot of code: http://www.vogella.de/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html