# android mobile socket open

Tags: android, sockets

Why Socket can be open on the android emulator and connect to the python server code and open a socket  !! In other Hand When i run same android code on the mobile it doesn't run . didnt open a socket ..Any suggestion what is the problem and how to solve such thing

```
enter code here
import sys
from threading import Thread
import socket
import MySQLdb

allClients=[]

 class Client(Thread):

def __init__(self,clientSocket):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.sockfd = clientSocket #socket client
            self.name = ""
            self.nickName = ""

def newClientConnect(self):

  allClients.append(self.sockfd)
  while True:


        while True:

            try:
                 rm= self.sockfd.recv(2048)
                 print rm
                 i=0

                 while (i<2):

                    if   (rm) == row[i][0]:                   
                        reply="\n Welcome to our game %s: %s"%(rm,row[i][1])
                        self.sockfd.send(reply)
                        break

                    else:

                        i=i+1
                    if i==2:
                        reply="\n Error opaa ba2a"
                        self.sockfd.send(reply)
                        i=0
                        break
                 break

            except ValueError:
                   self.sockfd.send("\n UNVAlied Comment ")


def run(self):
            self.newClientConnect()
            while True:
                    buff = self.sockfd.recv(2048)
                    if buff.strip() == 'quit':
                         self.sockfd.close()
                         break # Exit when break
                    else:
                         self.sendAll(buff)
                   #Main
            if __name__ == "__main__":

          #Server Connection to socket:
             IP = '50.0.10.107'
          PORT = 5807
         serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        serversocket.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1 )
            print ("Server Started")
        try:
    serversocket.bind(('',54633))
except ValueError,e:
    print e
serversocket.listen(5)


db= MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",
              user="root",
              passwd="newpassword",
              db="new_schema")


     x=db.cursor()
     x.execute("SELECT *  FROM lolo")
      row = x.fetchall()


        print "Connected to the Database"


        while True:
    (clientSocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    print 'New connection from ', address
    ct = Client(clientSocket)
    ct.start()




    __all__ = ['allClients','Client']
```

The python code and the server code it map and button when click on button connection start and it work great on the emulator

Comment: Ugh learn english.  What I can gather:  He can open a socket from the emulator to his python server but not on the actual device

Comment: yes True . and sorry for my English i will try to learn better

Comment: So John After Getting My Question any suggestion ??

Comment: Sorry, I personally don't know much about sockets on android.  I'd suggest posting your connection code for both server and client, as well as mentioning what devices and platforms you are testing on.

Comment: Samsung Mini Galaxy platform 2.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connection between Android phone and python server suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034271/connection-between-android-phone-and-python-server-suggestion)

Answer (score 3):

Could be a number of thing:

1. You don't have networking permissions enabled in your manifest file
2. Your wifi / 3G is disabled
3. If your server is on your personal computer and you're connected to the internet using a router then you need to redirect the port you're using for socket communication from the router to your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your code works on emulator but not on real phone, that could be a network issue. Emulator depends on LAN to access your server and phone access through 3G network. Is your server accessible through internet?

Comment: i guess there is nothing in my code let the server to access internet Or what do you think ?